# Trying to create multiple obstacles as the frameNo increases

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replicate a game tutorial from w3 schools. Everything has been successful so far up until the part where I have to create multiple obstacles by defining it as an array and calling upon the .push() function every 150th interval.

When I try to run the game with this exact Javascript code it keeps returning the error in my console as

> pbf.js:108 Uncaught TypeError: pbfObstacle.push is not a function
>       at updateGameArea (pbf.js:108)

I was wondering if anyone can help me fix this so that instead of returning the console error it will create multiple Obstacles as intended. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

**Here is my javascript:**

```
// This will declare the variables to create the canvas on the <body>
var gameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.style.width = "1920px";
        this.canvas.style.height = "auto";
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        // creating frames that we can use to count
        this.frameNo = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
            window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
                gameArea.keys = (gameArea.keys || []);
                gameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = true;
            })
            window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
                gameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = false;
            })
        },
        clear : function() {
            this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        },
        // this will clear the interval when one component crashes another
        stop : function() {
            clearInterval(this.interval);
        }
    }

// This will make the game piece
var pbfGamePiece;

function component (width, height, color, x, y) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.color = color;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = gameArea.context;
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY;
    }
    // this will check if one component crashes another
    this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
        var myleft = this.x;
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var otherleft = otherobj.x;
        var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
        var othertop = otherobj.y;
        var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
        var crash = true;
        if ((mybottom < othertop) || 
                (mytop > otherbottom) ||
                (myright < otherleft) ||
                (myleft > otherright)) {
                    crash = false;
                }
                return crash;
    }
}
// This will create the pbfObstacle into an array
var pbfObstacle = [];

// This loads the function tagged on the <body>
function startGame() {
    gameArea.start();
    pbfGamePiece = new component(8, 15, "#3baffc", 15, 115);
    pbfObstacle = new component(3, 50, "#ff4000", 95, 100);
}


// This clears and updates the game area while also adding multiple obstacles
function updateGameArea() {
    var x, y;
    for (i = 0; i < pbfObstacle.length; i += 1) {
        if (pbfGamePiece.crashWith(pbfObstacle[i])) {
            gameArea.stop();
            return;
        } 
    }
    gameArea.clear();
    gameArea.frameNo += 1;
    if (gameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
        x = gameArea.canvas.width;
        y = gameArea.canvas.height - 200;
        pbfObstacle.push(new component(10, 200, "green", x, y));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < pbfObstacle.length; i += 1) {
        pbfObstacle[i].x += -1;
        pbfObstacle[i].update();
    }
    pbfGamePiece.newPos();    
    pbfGamePiece.update();
}

// This function returns every true interval
function everyinterval(n) {
    if((gameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {return true;}
    return false;
}

// These functions will allow the buttons to create movement of the objects

function moveup() {
    pbfGamePiece.speedY -= 1;
}

function movedown() {
    pbfGamePiece.speedY += 1;
}

function moveleft() {
    pbfGamePiece.speedX -= 1;
}

function moveright() {
    pbfGamePiece.speedX += 1;
}

// This will stop the game pieces animation from not stopping

function stopMove() {
    pbfGamePiece.speedX = 0;
    pbfGamePiece.speedY = 0;
}
```

**The HTML is very straight forward:**

```
<body onload="startGame()">
....
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function startGame() {
  gameArea.start();
  pbfGamePiece = new component(8, 15, "#3baffc", 15, 115);
  pbfObstacle.push(new component(3, 50, "#ff4000", 95, 100));
}
```

in `startGame()` you are assigning new Component to `pbfObstacle`. So its showing error. push that `new component` it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to remove the pbfObstacle line in the startGame function.

```
// This loads the function tagged on the <body>
function startGame() {
    gameArea.start();
    pbfGamePiece = new component(8, 15, "#3baffc", 15, 115);
}
```